# Выполнить действия при закрытии окна

Tags: java, javafx

Есть контроллер EditController. Как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на крестик (закрытие окна) выполнялись какие-то действия? А именно при закрытии окна нужно выполнить `checkBox1.setSelected = false;`. Где это прописать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPD: расписал более подробно:**

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public Stage primaryStage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/view/main_view.fxml"));

        Parent root = loader.load();
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, primaryStage.getWidth(),primaryStage.getHeight());


        primaryStage.setTitle("SOME_TITLE");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();

        MainViewController controller = loader.getController();

        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(controller.getCloseEventHandler());
    }
}
```

В самом контроллере:

```
public class MainViewController {

    //Тут описание всяких контроллов

        private javafx.event.EventHandler<WindowEvent> closeEventHandler = new javafx.event.EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                    //ТУТ НЕОБХОДИМАЯ ЛОГИКА
                }
            };

        public javafx.event.EventHandler<WindowEvent> getCloseEventHandler(){
        return closeEventHandler;
        }

}
```

Comment: А где лучше всего прописать код? Дело в том что при закрытии данного окна не нужно выходить из приложения полностью, а всего лишь скрывать окно. Вот я не знаю Где именно нужно прописать Ваш код.

Comment: Тут я не претендую на истину в последней инстанции. Но я бы реализовал `EventHandler` в контроллере и передал его в `public void start(Stage primaryStage) `. Ссылку на контроллер можно получить с помощью: `MainViewController controller = loader.getController();`

Comment: Спасибо.. будем пробовать.

Comment: О вот этот код скорее всего мне подойдет.. Потому что мне в методе handle в самом контроллере нужно сброить чекбоксы, текстовые поля при закрытии окна. Можете пояснить как работает данный код?

Comment: @Сергей не забудьте отметить ответ как правильный, чтобы другим было проще его найти.

Comment: Отметил. Ваш код помог, только хотел бы разобраться в нем более детально

Comment: @Сергей напишите, что конкретно не ясно, попробую ответить.

Comment: Мне кажется нужно написать не controller.setOnCloseRequest(controller.getCloseEventHandler());

а primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(controller.getCloseEventHandler());

Comment: @Сергей Вы все верно заметили. Прошу прощения за опечатку. Ответ исправил

Comment: Разобрался теперь с кодом. Спасибо большое.